# Fine perimeter of trapezium $EDBC$?

Tags: geometry

Consider the figure below.

$ED$ is parallel to $BC$. $EC=6, DB=8$, and $\angle CAB=90
$ degree.

I want to find the perimeter of trapezium $EDBC$.

[image]

How should I proceed here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: the radius of the circle is $24/5$. To see why, drop a perpendicular from $D$ to $BC$: the triangle thus created is similar to $ABC$ and $ADE$, and its sides are then in the ratio $3:4:5$.

Comment: I tried doing that. But I am not able to see how we can conclude that radius is 4.8 Can you help a little bit here.

Comment: All right triangles in that picture are similar between them, and their sides are in the ratio $3:4:5$.

Answer (score 1):

Let 's denote angles to vertices; we have:

$\tan b=6/8$,  so,  $\cos(b)=4/5$

Drop a perpendicular  from O to BC at point E then:

$r= 6 \times (4/5)=24/5$ is the radius of circle. Drop another perpendicular from O to AB at point F we have:

$FD=(24/5)/ \tan (b)=(24/5)/(3/4)=\frac{32}{5} $ so:

$ AB=8+32/5+24/5=96/5$

$CB= (96/5)/(4/5)=24$

$ED=(56/5)/(4/5)=14$

So perimeter is:

$24+14+6+8=52$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let [.] denote areas. Then,

$$[ADE] = \frac12 r(AE+AD),\>\>\>\>\>[ABC] = \frac12 r(AC+AB+BC),\>\>\>\>\>
[EDBC] = \frac12r(DE+BC)$$

Recognize $[ABC]-[ADE] = [EDBC]$ to get

$$DE = (AC-AE) + (AB-AD) = 6+8 =14$$

Then, $BC = ED + FB = 14+\sqrt{6^2+8^2}=24$. Thus, the perimeter is $6+8+14+24=52$.