# Find the new lengths of a right triangle if hypotenuse shifts to a distance W

Tags: geometry

[image]

Given that sides $AC$ and $A'C'$ are parallel and lengths $AB$ and $BC$ are known. Also the distance between $AC$ and $A'C'$ is known and is $w$, What I would like to know is the lengths $AA'$ and $CC'$ and also the difference between AC and A'C'

Appreciate any pointers. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also we need to find the difference AC - A'C'

Comment: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3289002/how-to-find-the-perimeter-of-trapezium-edbc) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let's assume $AB=a$, $BC=b$, $A'B=a'$, $BC'=b'$ and $A'D=C'D'=w$.

Clearly triangle $ABC$ and $ADA'$ are similar. Therefore,

$$\dfrac{AA'}{AC}=\dfrac{A'D}{BC}$$

Or

$$\dfrac{AA'}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\dfrac{w}{b}$$

$$AA'=\dfrac{w}{b}\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

Similarly,

Triangle $BCA$ and $D'CC'$ are similar. Therefore,

$$\dfrac{CC'}{AC}=\dfrac{C'D'}{AB}$$

Or

$$\dfrac{CC'}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}=\dfrac{w}{a}$$

$$CC'=\dfrac{w}{a}\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. So then the difference between AC and A'C' (which I had asked in comments) should be : w(a/b+b/a) is that right?

Comment: @Kumar If you mean $AC-A'C'$ then it's correct

Answer (score 0):

Draw a perpendicular from $A'$ to $AC$. Let $X$ be the point of intersection of the perpendicular and $AC$. $A'AX$ is a right triangle, similar to $ABC$. $A'X=W$. From similarity of triangles, $AX:W=AB:BC$ or $AX=\frac{AB \cdot W}{BC}$. Now use Pythagorean theorem to find $AA'$. Similarly, construct triangle $CC'Y$ and obtain that $CY=\frac{BC \cdot W}{AB}$.